# How can I Sign up a user on firebase?

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter

I want to sign up a user on firebase that I store in a variable.
Here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/custom_shape.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/customappbar.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/responsive_ui.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/textformfield.dart';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  bool checkBoxValue = false;
  double _height;
  double _width;
  double _pixelRatio;
  bool _large;
  bool _medium;
  TextEditingController emailEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String email;

  void validation() {
// email should be instantiated here
  email = emailEditingController.text;
    bool emailvalidated = EmailValidator.validate(email);
    if (emailvalidated) {
      print('Email validated');
    } else{
      print('email not validated');
     }
 }

  Widget clipShape() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.75,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: CustomShapeClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: _large
                  ? _height / 8
                  : (_medium ? _height / 7 : _height / 6.5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.orange[200], Colors.pinkAccent],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.5,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: CustomShapeClipper2(),
            child: Container(
              height: _large
                  ? _height / 12
                  : (_medium ? _height / 11 : _height / 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.orange[200], Colors.pinkAccent],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: _height / 5.5,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  offset: Offset(1.0, 10.0),
                  blurRadius: 20.0),
            ],
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('Adding photo');
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add_a_photo,
                size: _large ? 40 : (_medium ? 33 : 31),
                color: Colors.orange[200],
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget form() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: _width / 12.0, right: _width / 12.0, top: _height / 20.0),
      child: Form(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            firstNameTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(height: _height / 60.0),
            lastNameTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(height: _height / 60.0),
            emailTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(height: _height / 60.0),
            phoneTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(height: _height / 60.0),
            passwordTextFormField(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget firstNameTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      icon: Icons.person,
      hint: "First Name",
    );
  }

   Widget emailTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      // assign your email controller to the custom text field here,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      icon: Icons.email,
      hint: "Email ID",
      textEditingController: emailEditingController,
    );
  }
  Widget acceptTermsTextRow() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height / 100.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Checkbox(
              activeColor: Colors.orange[200],
              value: checkBoxValue,
              onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  checkBoxValue = newValue;
                });
              }),
          Text(
            "I accept all terms and conditions",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: _large ? 12 : (_medium ? 11 : 10)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget button() {
    return RaisedButton(
      elevation: 0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
      onPressed: () {
        validation();
      },
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Text(
          'SIGN UP',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: _large ? 14 : (_medium ? 12 : 10)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I would appreciate your help.
But I need to auto login for my app too and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are asking is to sign in with firebase to your app using `Email and Password`.

In that case. The article below covers all what you want. 
Sign in with email and password using firebase in flutter.

[Sign in with email and password using firebase in flutter](https://itnext.io/flutter-firebase-auth-starter-project-b0f91a6503b7)

I hope this answers your question.

**UPDATED**

Here is the link to the `Github` repository of the article above :
[Github Repository](https://github.com/delay/flutter_firebase_auth_starter)

Comment: medium site does not allow me like usual??

Comment: I don't get your question @Omar Yacop

Comment: I can't go to this site

Comment: I 've tried so many times but it always says connection reset

Comment: No worries, I added the ```Github Link``` of the article. Check the updated answer for it.

Comment: so should I add the app to firebase and replace the API key and that's it

Comment: These parameters are not defined:
headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: _darkTextColor),
    bodyText1: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: _darkTextColor),
    bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.grey),
    button: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15.0, color: _darkTextColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
    headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: _darkTextColor),
    subtitle1: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: _darkTextColor),

Comment: Add the ```app_themes.dart``` file in the github repo to your project. @OmarYacop

Comment: It is needed to change the SDK path here right?
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"

Comment: Could not read script 'C:\flutter files\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' as it does not exist.

Comment: The app_plugin_loader.gradle is not in the specified folder, so what should I do.

Comment: check this https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/02/25/using-firebase-auth-in-flutter/